# Visual Studio 2019 cant find many header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, graphics, game-engine

I've been working on my game engine for a while and for some reason all of a sudden I came up with an error that many header files are missing. I checked the console and there is no errors in the code and also I already compiled the project before. It happened after I removed Windows files from my old disc that I dont use as primary disc anymore and visual studio mightve used those files from that path. I already tried repairing Visual Studio but it didn't fix the problem. Here is a screenshot of the errors: [image: Errors showing that header files cannot be found]

**ANSWER: The Windows SDK was missing and so, the files couldn't be found. I downloaded the sdk from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)**

Comment: Is your include folder correct?

Comment: Yes, my include folder has glfw, gl, assimp and glm which are all meant to be included in project

Comment: @ERNEST326 Whoops I didn't see the source code, my bad. Out of interest, what are the column headers for that error table?

Comment: @ERNEST326 the errors are mostly about C standard headers. Are you sure you haven't removed Windows SDK files by accident? Do you have references to your old disc anywhere in the solution?

Comment: I most likely removed the windows sdk that visual studio used. I got the files on anoter disc but not sure how to change path for windows sdk

Comment: The Windows SDK file was missing so thats the reason why my project didnt work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

For your project, go to Project->Properties and verify that the project is set to use a version of Windows SDK that is installed on the General tab as well as a platform toolset that is installed. Also make sure that at the dropdowns at the top for configuration/platform are the environment you are currently testing in (ex. Debug x86 would be Debug Win32).

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure the include / library path don't contain any space. After I moved the project to a spaceless path, and replaced the content in .vcxproj, header files were loaded.