# Cannot find any header files c++ project in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

For the past hour I have been looking at multiple stack overflow questions trying including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679720/c-cannot-open-source-file) one and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335408/where-does-visual-studio-look-for-c-header-files) one trying to figure out why visual studio cannot open typical source files like stdio.h

I am starting out by building a new project and then selecting the "console app" option, but when I try to compile and run the simple hello world program I get the errors shown below.

[image]

*Edit*:

Here is the code that is generated by default when choosing the console application option in visual studio that I am trying to run:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you show the actual code? "Simple hello world program" doesn't tell us much. Also, do any of the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777424/visual-studio-2017-errors-on-standard-headers) question help?

Comment: I have now edited the question with the code. It is the default code that is generated by visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I thought I had the Widows 10 SDK installed, but apparently I did not. I found the answer using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213725/visual-studio-2019-cant-find-many-header-files) stack overflow thread.

I had to download the Windows 10 SDK from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/) and restart the visual studio IDE and it worked straight away.

Comment: I fear you installed things incorrectly originally and may have made it worse. You do not need to install the Windows 10 SDK from anywhere other than through the Visual Studio installer. By Selecting the "Desktop C++ Development" workload the SDK is installed for you.

Comment: What do you suggest I do now? Should I uninstall visual studio and reinstall it ensuring that I install the "Desktop C++ Development"?

Comment: You lucked out that the install directions say you can use either method, but in the future you can do everything through the VS Installer; especially for SDK and VS updates.

Comment: @user13834264 I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.